# Can I SSH with a UID instead of a username?

Tags: openssh

So, I'm working with a software product that deploys as an OVA.  They don't generate new SSH keys upon install, so every VM deployment has the same keys.  And they allow key based login.

The admin user's uid is always 4001.  The admin username is decided at the time the OVA is deployed.

Is there a way to connect via SSH specifying a UID on the remote system instead of a username? :)

Comment: have you found an answer to this?